# Send SMS to multiple numbers using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sms-gateway

I have a link that works directly from browser that is the sms gateway we are using. I am trying to make to send sms to multiple numbers using php and mysql as database please help me with full code.

Comment: Have you googled the same question, there are alrady multiple posts that you can find.

Comment: Your question is too broad and you can use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for this!

Comment: You will need sms gateway which provide `REST Api` to send sms using php.

Comment: My link is following. Kindly help me for the full code. http://sms.indiabulksms.in/app/smsapi/index.php?key=987654321&campaign=0&routeid=8&type=text&contacts=999999999&senderid=smsing&msg=hello

Answer (score 0):

1.get all mobile numbers in array
2.fetch and run feach loop
3.put that senting code.
ex:

```
$data = array('9940272758','213456789','8973557140');
foreach($data as $value){
  sendapi($value,"hi","somthing");
}
```

Comment: My link is following. Kindly help me for the full code. http://sms.indiabulksms.in/app/smsapi/index.php?key=987654321&campaign=0&routeid=8&type=text&contacts=999999999&senderid=smsing&msg=hello

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am getting following error while using your suggested code.

Answer (score 0):

`$result=$array();` //Get from database here assume it is `$result`

```
foreach($result as $mbl){
  sendapi($mbl['phone'],$mbl['message']);
}
```

Comment: My link is following. Kindly help me for the full code.                                                        http://sms.indiabulksms.in/app/smsapi/index.php?key=987654321&campaign=0&routeid=8&type=text&contacts=999999999&senderid=smsing&msg=hello

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am getting following error while using your suggested code